# Google-Visualization (Google-Charts)

Tags: arrays, charts, google-visualization

This is the last part of my code for Google Charts:

```
array.push("['" + tbl.rows[k].cells[l-1].innerHTML + "', " + tbl.rows[k].cells[l+10].innerHTML + "]");
      }
  }
//alert(array);
    
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

// Declare columns
data.addColumn('string', 'boxes');
data.addColumn('number', 'price');

// Add data.
 data.addRows([

['box1', 10.42],['box2', 14.77],['box3', 9.75],['box4', 1.43]  
//I put it manually and works. But If I type "array", does not work.

]);
        // Set Options
        var options = {
          title: 'Boxes (f) Prices',
          hAxis: {title: 'kind of boxes'},
          vAxis: {title: 'prices ($)'},
        };
        // Draw
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('myChart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

As you can see, the array is not the same every time.
At this particular time "alert(array);" gave this:

['box1', 10.42],['box2', 14.77],['box3', 9.75],['box4', 1.43]

I copy-paste it and the code works fine. But that's where I want the final result of "array.push" to go. Ιf I type "array", the code does not work.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, just build a normal array, no need to use string concatenation, here...

```
array.push([tbl.rows[k].cells[l-1].innerHTML, parseFloat(tbl.rows[k].cells[l+10].innerHTML)]);
```

then when you want to add to the datatable...

```
data.addRows(array);
```